# Set border and background color of radio group to transparent with pdf-lib library

Tags: javascript, express, pdf, pdf-lib.js

I have a use case where I am using the [Hopding/pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib) library to remove radio groups and recreate the removed radio group in a PDF to reassign the radio button values. The first image is the original look of the round and square radio buttons.

[image]

After creating the radio group, the radio buttons now have a border and the square radio buttons are now having a circle border within a box. I could make them to look identical as the original design but that requires me to open the PDF on Adobe Acrobat, go to Prepare Form, and set the background and border color to No Color.

Also notice that in the original's image, the square radio button has a cross marker but the recreated radio button has a dot market instead. I could set it back to using the cross marker from Adobe Acrobat but I prefer to do that on the code level. The code below is how I recreate the radio group.

What I am trying to achieve but couldn't (no documentations):

1. Set the recreated radio group's border and background to transparent or No Color
2. Keep the default marker style

```
const radio = pdfForm.createRadioGroup(radioInfo.radioFieldName);
        for (let j = 0; j < radioToBeRecreated[index].totalNumOfRadioOptions; j++) {
          radio.addOptionToPage(j.toString(), pdfDoc.getPage(radioToBeRecreated[index].page), {
            x: radioToBeRecreated[index].dimens[j].x,
            y: radioToBeRecreated[index].dimens[j].y,
            width: radioToBeRecreated[index].dimens[j].width,
            height: radioToBeRecreated[index].dimens[j].height
            backgroundColor: undefined,
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderWidth: 0.6, // 0 doesn't work here
          });
```

[image]